# PHP Redirect-Login Error

Tags: php, authentication

When I try to login at my page, it is successfully connected, but when the page reloads, I'm getting redirected back at my login page, can someone help me?

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    $user["beta"] = "beta01key";
    if(!isset($_SESSION['ingelogd']))
    {
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
        {
            if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']))
            {
                exit('<br /><br /><html><body><div id="center"><h2> Login Status: <br/></h2><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold">Please fill in all fields!</span></div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1"></body>');
            }
            elseif ($user[$_POST['username']] != $_POST['password'])
            {
                exit('<br /><br /><div id="center"><h2> Login Status: <br/></h2><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold">Your username/password is wrong!</span></div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1"></body>');
            }
            else
            {            if (!isset($_SESSION['ingelogd']))
                echo '</body><div id="center"><h2> Login Status: <br/></h2><span style="color:green; font-weight: bold">You are now logged in!</span></div></body></head>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            exit('<br /><br />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/body.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/button.css">
    <div id="center">
            <form method="POST" action=""><p>
            Username:<br />
            <input type="text" name="username" /><br /><br />
            Password:<br />
            <input type="password" name="password" /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Login" /> <input type="reset" value="Empty fields" />
            </form></div>');
        }
    }
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/body.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not set your login flag `$_SESSION['ingelogd']` after logging-in. That is the reason.

Try this snippet on your `else` part

```
else {
    $_SESSION['ingelogd'] = TRUE;
    echo '</body><div id="center"><h2> Login Status: <br/></h2><span style="color:green; font-weight: bold">You are now logged in!</span></div></body></head>';
}
```